# Java: Play a sound more than once

Tags: java, audio

I have recently been learning how to add sounds in java. Currently, I have this code that works, but it isn't always playing at the right time, or sometimes it doesn't even play at all. How could I get the sound to play each time the `play()` method is fired at the right timing? This happens every time I `click` on a `component`, by the way.

```
public class Sound {

    private File sndFile0;
    private AudioInputStream au;
    private Clip cl;
    private DataLine.Info info;

    public Sound() {
        try {
            sndFile0 = new File(getClass().getResource("/sound/vir1.wav").toURI());
            au = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sndFile0);
            info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, au.getFormat());
            cl = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            cl.open(au);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        cl.start();
        cl.setFramePosition(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: just restart on Type.STOP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557903/how-can-i-wait-for-a-java-sound-clip-to-finish-playing-back

Comment: @MichaelD. It's weird, If I click on the components fast enough or after the clip ends, the sound will restart, otherwise if it's somewhere in the middle it won't do anything. I change the play code to this: http://pastebin.com/KNAmd9Mc

Comment: if it is already playing you want to restart it? that's a stop() reset() and a play() or so... not sure

Comment: After some testing I found out that the `LineListener` didn't do a thing, the only thing that is allowing the sound to play more than once is the `cl.setFramePosition(0)`, which works sometimes. I even tried using `cl.stop` at the beginning of the play method, it didn't help at all. So basically it threw me back to my original `play()` method.

Comment: SOLVED(ish). What I was able to get it to do is each time they click on the component, it will just reload the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. What I did was I went ahead and loaded the sound file each time the component was clicked on.

Comment: Is this the only way to play a sound repetitively?

Comment: This is probably a less suitable way to do that. I would not recommend doing it this way. A third party library may be more suitable.

Comment: Alright.  This method works for me until I have lots of consecutive sounds (an automatic gun shooting) and then I get an out of memory crash.