# No Sound When Trying to Play Audio (.wav) Files

Tags: java, audio, avaudioplayer, playing

I have a very simple class that can play a sound file with the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Sound{

private Clip sound;

public Sound(String location){

    try{ 
        sound = AudioSystem.getClip();
        File file = new File(location);
        sound.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
    }
    catch(IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException error){
        System.out.println(error);
    }

}

public void play(){

    sound.start();

}

}
```

However, when I create an instance of this class and call the play function on it I don't get any sound. I hear a pop when the sound starts and when it ends but not the actual file. Also I don't get any errors of any sort.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which is the file format? Does it uses a codec?

Comment: No, It's a normal .WAV file and I have tried different ones.

Comment: You have to wait for the clip to finish, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557903/how-can-i-wait-for-a-java-sound-clip-to-finish-playing-back)

Comment: This answer did not do the trick for me. I know the clip is starting and it ends because there is a quiet *pop* noise, but I can't hear the actual file.

Comment: why don't you use javax.media package?

Comment: have a look at this link which may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
File soundFile = new File( "something.wav" );
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( soundFile );
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();//This plays the audio
```

You might have to use `AudioSystem.getClip()` **after** loading the audio stream.

Answer (score 1):

Use this and note this is not my code it's from here: [How to play .wav files with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416935/how-to-play-wav-files-with-java)
The only thing I did was post it here and optimize it a little.

```
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
private AudioInputStream audioStream;
private SourceDataLine sourceLine;
/**
 * @param filename the name of the file that is going to be played
 */
 public void playSound(String filename){
try {
    audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioStream.getFormat()));
    sourceLine.open(audioStream.getFormat());
} catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sourceLine.start();
int nBytesRead = 0;
byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (nBytesRead != -1) {
    try {
        nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int nBytesWritten = sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
    }
}
sourceLine.drain();
sourceLine.close();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that the audio file one is using the frequent culprit. Java, apparently, cannot play compressed sound files or something like that. It plays linear PCM files only. I could be wrong about the only. Anyone have an example that plays any type of sound file?