# While loop not working In audio player

Tags: java, swing, audio, while-loop, javasound

I'm using a sound player and I'm trying to create a while loop that knows when to terminate the `JFrame` it's playing in. The while loop should loop while the clip (recording) is playing and end when the clip is done. But here's the deal: The while loop only works when it prints something out, which I DON'T want it to do?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SoundClipTest extends JFrame {

public SoundClipTest() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  try {
     // Open an audio input stream.
    File soundFile = new File("Testing/recording (2).wav");
    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    //URL url = new URL("http://maximumdonline.com/miscwavs/pacman.wav");
    //AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
     // Get a sound clip resource.
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

     // Open audio clip and load samples from the audio input stream.
     clip.open(audioIn);
     clip.start();
     this.setVisible(true);
     this.setVisible(false);
     boolean run = true;

     //problem While Loop
     while(clip.isActive()){
          //Only works when I print something out during the loop:
         //System.out.println(run);

     }
     //Test While Loop has ended.
     run = false;
     System.out.println(run);
     //Close JFrame
  } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Note: Most of this sound code came from
https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html
It works. I've tested it, but my while loop is crying!

Comment: Gieva a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557903/how-can-i-wait-for-a-java-sound-clip-to-finish-playing-back

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to approach this task is to add a `LineListener` to the `Clip`. A `Clip` implements `javax.sound.sampled.Line` interface, so we can use [`Line.addLineListener(LineListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#addLineListener-javax.sound.sampled.LineListener-)..

> Adds a listener to this line. Whenever the line's status changes, the listener's `update()` method is called with a `LineEvent` object that describes the change.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your code to

`while (clip.isActive()) {
                if(!clip.isRunning())
                    clip.stop();
            }`

This did the trick for me